# How can you generate a POLLPRI event on a regular file?

Tags: python, sockets

When working with sysfs GPIO on Linux, you are instructed to `poll` for `POLLPRI` and `POLLERR` events.

This is quite easy:

```
poll = select.poll()
poll.register(filename, select.POLLPRI | select.POLLERR)
result = poll.poll(timeout=timeout)
```

However, I would like to write tests for this code, and simulation tests for the application relying on it. So, I need to be able to cause a `POLLPRI` event.

I have tried using a Unix domain socket, but then I am unable to open the file for reading after the domain socket has connected (`errno 6`, no such device). I also tried using a socket with `SOCK_DGRAM`, but that either fails to find the file if not already created, or yields connection refused.

I want a way to open a regular file or create a file that can be opened like a regular file and be able to send it a stream of messages that are treated as "urgent data". ie `MSG_OOB`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can achieve this by polling a sysctl exposed in procfs. If you look at the [poll implementation in procfs for the `sys` subdirectory](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/proc_sysctl.c?v=3.10#L544), you'll see that any sysctl that implements notifications for poll will return a mask that includes `POLLERR|POLLPRI`. So how do we figure out what sysctls implement this? We look for uses of `proc_sys_poll_notify`!

One such place is in [`proc_do_uts_string`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/utsname_sysctl.c?v=3.10#L47), which implements a number of sysctls under `/proc/sys/kernel`. Most of these are read-only, but `hostname` and `domainname` can be written (see also their [table entries](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/utsname_sysctl.c?v=3.10#L92)).

Of course, this is going to require root privileges to be able to write to e.g. `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname`.

This is probably the easiest way to do such a thing while staying within a synthetic filesystem implementation. Of course, the only *real* way to test your code is to `poll(2)` one of your pins, press a button, and see if you get your rising / falling signal interrupts.

Note: [sysfs also does this for edge nodes in the tree](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/sysfs/file.c?v=3.10#L421):

```
>>> import select
>>> f = open('/sys/bus/clockevents/devices/clockevent0/uevent', 'r')
>>> p = select.poll()
>>> p.register(f, select.POLLPRI | select.POLLERR)
>>> result = p.poll(10)
>>> result
[(3, 10)]
```

`10` is of course `POLLPRI (0x2) | POLLERR (0x8)`. I got the same results using `/sys/power/state` as my input. Basically, if you poll any user-readable, non-directory file entry in sysfs, you'll get `POLLPRI | POLLERR` back.

Comment: Very cool. I'm not going to accept as the answer because of the root requirement and the potential side effects of touching things in /proc/sys/kernel, but it does provide what is asked, so bounty for you!

Comment: You could use a similar methodology to dig for other instances of POLLPRI in synthetic filesystems; you might find some interface that always returns this -- I didn't find anything easy, but I only looked for a few minutes and I don't know what devices you have available. Glad that this was at least some help!

Comment: Found a non-root-needing strategy, polling files in sysfs. Perhaps this is a satisfactory answer to the question?

Comment: Using something similar to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html doesn't seem to do the trick when polling on the suggested files. Is this system dependent? I'm testing on a GCP VM.